# Query with Interval in Oracle (using JFreeChart)

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, jfreechart, intervals

I am assembling a query to show a experiment in JFreeChart.The Query works fine, but not the displaying in the JFreeChart.Its assembly the intervals as String (interval like 60bigger than TAsmaller than120 is last in the chart, should be second).I will put an example using five intervals of 60minutes each (TA is a numeric field and means Time Average):

```
    SELECT INTERVAL, COUNT(*) TOTAL FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN TA>0 AND TA<=60.00 THEN  '0<TA<=60.00' WHEN TA>60.00 AND TA<=120.00 THEN '60.00<TA<=120.00' WHEN TA>120.00 AND TA<=180.00 THEN '120.00<TA<=180.00' WHEN TA>180.00 AND TA<=240.00 THEN '180.00<TA<=240.00' WHEN TA>240.00 THEN '240.00<TA' END   INTERVAL, TA  FROM MP) GROUP BY INTERVAL HAVING INTERVAL IS NOT NULL ORDER BY INTERVAL
```

How can i do that to display correctely the intervals without destroying/damaging much my query, because it will be assembled on-the-fly depending of user choice.

Answer (score 0):

If the `INTERVAL` column will always start with a valid number followed by `<`, you can convert its first value to a numeric for sorting:

```
SELECT INTERVAL, COUNT(*) TOTAL
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN TA>0 AND TA<=60.00 THEN  '0<TA<=60.00' 
      WHEN TA>60.00 AND TA<=120.00 THEN '60.00<TA<=120.00' 
      WHEN TA>120.00 AND TA<=180.00 THEN '120.00<TA<=180.00' 
      WHEN TA>180.00 AND TA<=240.00 THEN '180.00<TA<=240.00' 
      WHEN TA>240.00 THEN '240.00<TA'
    END INTERVAL,
    TA 
  FROM MP
  )
  WHERE INTERVAL IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY INTERVAL
  ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(INTERVAL, 1, INSTR(INTERVAL, '<') - 1));
```

Also, I've changed the `HAVING Interval IS NOT NULL` to `WHERE Interval IS NOT NULL` because `HAVING` is for aggregated values such as `COUNT(*)`, not for grouping values like `INTERVAL`.

---

**Addendum** If the number of intervals will vary, the query below may work out better for you. It calculates the interval text just like the query above, but it can handle any number of intervals. The first `CASE` condition handles values outside the range (`n<TA`); the second condition handles values within the range (`m<TA<=n`).

I've pointed the values you'll need to set for each query.

```
SELECT Interval, COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT
    TA,
    CASE
      WHEN TA > Parm_IntSize * Parm_IntCount THEN
        TO_CHAR(Parm_IntSize * Parm_IntCount) || '<TA'
      ELSE
        TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TA / Parm_IntSize) * Parm_IntSize)
          || '<='
          || TO_CHAR((TRUNC(TA / Parm_IntSize) + 1) * Parm_IntSize)
      END AS Interval
  FROM MP
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
      60 AS Parm_IntSize,    -- Specify interval size here
      4 AS Parm_IntCount     -- Specify number of intervals here
    FROM DUAL
  ) Parms
)
WHERE Interval IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Interval
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(Interval, 1, INSTR(Interval, '<') - 1))
```

Comment: Ed Gibbs, the table name is MP(i editted, that table is of other project i messed assembling the query).I have a problem with your aproach: I dont know how many intervals till the user digit that.Example: begins in 60 minutes and number of intervals is 10(will go till 540...).There is a way to put something like:ORDER BY INTERVAL AS NUMERIC ?

Comment: @LeeP - OK, I understand a bit better now. I've edited my answer to order by the numeric value of `INTERVAL` rather than creating a separate column for ordering. I've also added a query that will adapt based on the number of intervals and the interval size - I've had to do something similar before. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ed Gibbs, i am trying your first query, but i am getting ora-00933.See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/19307  I can not see the error in your query.

Comment: Sorry about that - I got the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` out of order. The `WHERE` comes first, then `GROUP BY`. It's fixed in the answer.

Comment: Ed Gibbs, i am always receiving 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722 invalid number in your fist query.

Comment: @LeeP - I tried the query on a local copy of what I think your table looks like, and it worked. I may have made a bad assumption about your table and/or data. If you'd like to keep trying this approach could you create a SQL Fiddle with a table and data?

Comment: Ed Gibbs, that function TO_NUMBER is correct? I tried separatelly and Oracle(My Oracle is 10g XE) gave the same error(ORA-01722).

Comment: I'm on Oracle 11, but I've been using `TO_NUMBER` since at least version 8. I get ORA-01722 if I try `SELECT TO_NUMBER('aasd') FROM DUAL` but something like `SELECT TO_NUMBER('1234.56') FROM DUAL` works. `TO_NUMBER(null)` of course returns null. The value you're passing to `TO_NUMBER` probably has non-numeric characters. Try to find out what's being passed to `TO_NUMBER` in your query. I don't think it's the values from your question (`'0<TA<=60.00'` and so forth) because I tested those here and they worked. Or if you prefer, create a SQL Fiddle with schema and data and I'll take a look.

Comment: Ed Gibbs, strange a simple code like that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d021/4  works flawless. Note: there is no NULL in the TA field and all values are between 2 and 5679,9012434556(yes, there are some huge ones).I cant put a representative sample to you because there are three hundred thousand rows.